# How to manage photo stickers remove and scale buttons in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an android photo editor app where user can add photo stickers and each sticker has several buttons like remove, scale and flip. I am using this source code for image stickers:

https://github.com/niravkalola/Android-StickerView

Now the problem is when I want to save the screenshot the photo is saving with those stickers options buttons (remove, scale and flip buttons). But the photo should be captured or saved only with those stickers not the options buttons.

Can you help me how to remove or hide those options buttons for each stickers during screen capturing?

I can use View.Gone option but I didn't find how to identity those buttons because those are View and ImageView and there don't have any identity to retrieve I think. So any one can help me reviewing the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see your stickerView class.In that a method is for hiding all icons and border.

```
public void setControlItemsHidden(boolean isHidden){
        if(isHidden) {
            iv_border.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            iv_scale.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            iv_delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            iv_flip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            iv_border.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv_scale.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv_delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv_flip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
}
```

call this method where you want to hide icons.

```
sticker.setControlItemsHidden(true);
```

Comment: Would it hide all the *icons* which are shown in options or any *specific icon* ?

Comment: it will hide all icons. but if you want to hide any specific icon you need to remove extra visibility from this method.

Comment: Wow such  a great answer. Thank you so much Dhara.

Comment: @ShahriatHossain You should accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @jaydroider sure I will do it after implementing it. But I can't see any accept button. Can you help?

Comment: @ShahriatHossain There is no any *button* you can see correct option at lefr of answer below downvote arrow just check mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @DharaChandarana : do you have any updated stickerview library? Please share it if you have.